# Python: How to choose the hearts X,Y point from a list using Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I am making a own centroid tracker to follow some objects in a video.

From my detection function, I 'm getting a list, of list, from given data in this format:

```
[startX, startY, endX, endY,cX,cY,score]
```

this is an example when two objects were detected:

```
[[10,10,200,200,105,105,0.9],[350,120,410,500,380,310,0.7]]
```

I would like to make a function that returns the nearest (cX,cY) from that list, from given centroid points X,Y, from my tracker.

What is the best way to do that? All centroid trackers are using Euclidean Algorithm to calculate the distance. Is this the best way? Can someone explain it to me ?

i found this function on a website:

```
def pClosest(points, K):
 
    points.sort(key = lambda K: K[0]**2 + K[1]**2)
 
    return points[:K]
 
# Driver program
points = [[3, 3], [5, -1], [-2, 4]]
 
K = 2
 
print(pClosest(points, K))
```

how can i convert it for what i need?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong; you want the point with the least distance between the centroids of the list elements(cXi, cYi) and the point (X,Y)?

Comment: yes your right. but i need to get the index of my list to get all data from the point

Comment: Then i feel like min Euclidean Distance is the best approach you can apply.

Comment: Ok . but how to do a unction that get get a list of detection objects and a centroid and return the nearest one ?

Comment: Is the list of lists relatively stable, to which you have to compute the nearest point to X,Y for lots different X, Y?

Comment: yes in my function i nee dto give a certain X,Y point and the function will return the closest list comparing to its cX,cY in there

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `np.linalg.norm` with `ord=2` to get the euclidean distance between two numpy arrays. Applied to your example, you could use something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np

# Introduce a named tuple for named access to start/end/center points
DetectedObject = namedtuple("DetectedObject", 
                            ("start", "end", "center", "score"))

# I am storing your examples as DetectedObjects, each point is
# a vector of length 2.
examples = [DetectedObject(start=np.asarray([10, 10]),  # store point coordinates in array
                          end=np.asarray([200, 200]),
                          center=np.asarray([105, 105]),
                          score=0.9),
           DetectedObject(start=np.asarray([350, 120]),
                          end=np.asarray([410, 500]),
                          center=np.asarray([380, 310]),
                          score=0.7)]


def get_centers(objects):
    """Retrieve center points from DetectedObject."""
    return np.asarray(list(map(lambda o: o.center, objects)))

def get_closest_object_to_centroid(centroid, objects):
    """Given a centroid, extract the closest object from a collection of DetectedObjects."""
    centers = get_centers(objects)
    # instead of the norm you could also use np.sum((centroid-centers)**2, axis=1)
    closest_index = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(centroid-centers, ord=2, axis=1))
    return objects[closest_index]
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
closest = get_closest_object_to_centroid(centroid=np.asarray([10, 10]),
                                         objects=examples)
closest  # DetectedObject(start=array([10, 10]), end=array([200, 200]), center=array([105, 105]), score=0.9)
```

Answer (score 1):

i friend of mine sended to me this function:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
def closest_node(node, nodes):
    lista = []
    for item in nodes:
      lista.append([item[4],item[5]])
    return nodes[cdist([node], lista).argmin()]
 
# Driver program
points = [[10,10,200,200,105,105,0.9],[350,120,410,500,380,310,0.7]]
 
point = [30,50]

print(closest_node(point,points))
```

this worked fine